# Memcache System - Keys getting dropped frequently

Tags: google-app-engine

We currently have our application hosted in Google App Engine. Billing is enabled to that application. This application is still in beta that we are using for testing purpose. We have a logic of serving data from the Memcache if present, if not then we get the data from the datastore and update the memcache and serve the data. We are encountering strange behaviour related to Memcache. The data related to some keys in Memcache is getting dropped after few minutes after being set. We tried setting expiration time for the keys in the memcache, even that does not seem to work. Since the data is getting dropped from the memcache the data is again from the datastore which is increasing the billing for our application.

Currently nearly 80% of the billing is related to datastore read. The datastore read is high as the memcache is not working efficiently as it should be. Any insight why we are facing this issue would be really helpful.

Just an FYI, we are having around 75000 keys in the memcache with total size of 100 MB data. Our structure demands keeping such large number of keys in memcache, which I think should not be an issue.

Our application is being by 10 users and the billing amount per day is coming to around $40.

Thanks,
Krish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately memcache will evict keys as and when it requires. Setting the time to expire only means the item will be in memcache for **up to** the expiry time. 
Take a look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/memcache#what) regarding eviction.

Also, take a look at [this](http://bjk5.com/post/36567537399/dangers-of-using-memcache-counters-for-a-b-tests) for some more insight into ways around memcache issues.

Regarding your data structure, perhaps you could post a new question and we can see if others have advice for you.

Comment: Currently we have the dedicated Memcache support from 1.8.2 version of Google App Engine, We can prefer that,  that solves our problem.